# AngularJS : How to call a function within factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two function in factory

here is some code

```
.factory('getArticles', function ($http, $q) {
   return {
       abc : function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // my code 
            res= this. bcd();
            console.log(res); // undefined
          deferred.resolve(res);

          return deferred.promise;
       },
       bcd: function() {

        //some codee 

         return res; 

       }
   }

});
```

Now from controller i am calling abc  function 
but when i checked value of res under logs. this is showing undefined.

Any idea ? how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: May be you don't call abc function like getArticles.abc() and call this without correct this context?

Comment: i am able to call abc.

Comment: I tried to say that you can pass getArticles.abc function in callback and it can called without correct this context.

Comment: what make your bcd function ? maybe could you move it outside the .factory? look also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227644/angularjs-factory-http-service. to my understanding you should have only **one** function which return **one** result in your factory.

Comment: @HituBansal does it throw an error on calling this.bcd() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [From an angularJS factory, how can I call another function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234442/from-an-angularjs-factory-how-can-i-call-another-function)

Answer (score 3):

@Vineet's answer was correct for services, which are instantiated, but factories should just return an object.

I like @peek4y's answer, but it can be further improved, to still have abc() private:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var getArticles = function ($http, $q) {

  function bcd() {
    var res;
    // some logic
    return res;
  }

  function abc() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var res = bcd();
    console.log(res); 
    deferred.resolve(res);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  //return only the functions you want to expose

  return {
    abc: function () {
      return abc();
    }
  }
});

angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('getArticles', getArticles);

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Always, separate the concerns.

```
.factory('getArticles', function ($http, $q) {

  function abc() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    res= bcd();
    console.log(res); 
    deferred.resolve(res);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function bcd() {
    //some logic
    //Make sure your logic is returning proper value.
    return res;
  }


  //return only those functions you want to expose
  return {
    abc: abc
  }
});
```

in the return statement, you can basically expose only those methods, which you would consume.

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly as Mr. luschn has said but you can call your factory/service function from the controller by changing as below defined. You should define your function with `this` reference in factory

```
.factory('getArticles', function ($http, $q) {

       this.abc = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // my code 
            res= this. bcd();
            console.log(res); // undefined
          deferred.resolve(res);

          return deferred.promise;
       }

       this.bcd = function() {

        //some codee 

         return res; 

       }

});
```

in your controller you can call by

```
getArticles.abc()
```

If you need to call a factory's function from another factory function call simply

```
this.bcd();
```